# Agregar tag de Google Ads usando cURL en PHP

Tags: php, curl, google-ads

ando buscando ayuda con esto.

Tengo una conversion de google que reactivar, y para ello estaba usando curl.

Pero hasta el momento no puedo leer nada del response. Llega vacio.

```
// --------------------------------- Google ADS - Payment - Purchase
        $conversion_id = 'id-conversion1234';
        $conversion_label = 'label-conversion-1234';
        /* Event hit type. */           $p["t"] = "event";
        /* Event Category. Required. */ $p["ec"] = "Goal";
        /* Event Action. Required. */   $p["ea"] = "Google Ads Payment";
        /* Event label. */              $p["cl"] = $conversion_label;
        /* Event value. */              $p["ev"] = strval(round(100*$value));
        // Set up the cURL request
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/$conversion_id/?label=".$conversion_label);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($p));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($p));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // Execute the cURL request and retrieve the response
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        // Close the cURL request
        curl_close($ch);
```

Pero actualmente no esta funcionando, y no puedo ejecutar pagos para realizar pruebas.

Necesito algo más? Olvido algo? cualquier ayuda viene de manos.

Comment: que recives de respuesta??

Comment: Response no se ah cargado aun